# How to decrease the set temperature

Tags: c++, arduino, pid-controller, arduino-nano

I've been following [this tutorial to create an Arduino PID Temperature Controller](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-pid-temperature-controller).

I can increase the set temperature by rotating the rotary encoder clockwise however I can't decrease the set temperature even when I rotate the encoder anticlockwise. Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong :)

EDIT: the enconder works fine, I've tested it seperately but this code doesn't work. Thanks

The code is:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <PIDController.h>
#include "max6675.h"
// Define Rotary Encoder Pins
#define CLK_PIN 3
#define DATA_PIN 4
#define SW_PIN 2
// MAX6675 Pins
#define thermoDO  8
#define thermoCS  9
#define thermoCLK  10
// Mosfet Pin
#define mosfet_pin 11
// Serial Enable
#define __DEBUG__
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
#define OLED_RESET     -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
/*In this section we have defined the gain values for the 
 * proportional, integral, and derivative controller I have set
 * the gain values with the help of trial and error methods.
*/ 
#define __Kp 30 // Proportional constant
#define __Ki 0.7 // Integral Constant
#define __Kd 200 // Derivative Constant
int clockPin; // Placeholder por pin status used by the rotary encoder
int clockPinState; // Placeholder por pin status used by the rotary encoder
int set_temperature = 1; // This set_temperature value will increas or decreas if when the rotarty encoder is turned
float temperature_value_c = 0.0; // stores temperature value
long debounce = 0; // Debounce delay
int encoder_btn_count = 0; // used to check encoder button press
MAX6675 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO); // Create an instance for the MAX6675 Sensor Called "thermocouple"
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);// Create an instance for the SSD1306 128X64 OLED "display"
PIDController pid; // Create an instance of the PID controller class, called "pid"
void setup() {
#ifdef __DEBUG__
  Serial.begin(9600);
#endif
  pinMode(mosfet_pin, OUTPUT); // MOSFET output PIN
  pinMode(CLK_PIN, INPUT); // Encoer Clock Pin
  pinMode(DATA_PIN, INPUT); //Encoder Data Pin
  pinMode(SW_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);// Encoder SW Pin
  pid.begin();          // initialize the PID instance
  pid.setpoint(150);    // The "goal" the PID controller tries to "reach"
  pid.tune(__Kp, __Ki,__Kd);    // Tune the PID, arguments: kP, kI, kD
  pid.limit(0, 255);    // Limit the PID output between 0 and 255, this is important to get rid of integral windup!
  if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C)) {
#ifdef __DEBUG__
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
#endif
    for (;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }
  //
  display.setRotation(2); //Rotate the Display
  display.display(); //Show initial display buffer contents on the screen -- the library initializes this with an Adafruit splash screen.
  display.clearDisplay(); // Cleear the Display
  display.setTextSize(2); // Set text Size
  display.setTextColor(WHITE); // set LCD Colour
  display.setCursor(48, 0); // Set Cursor Position
  display.println("PID"); // Print the this Text
  display.setCursor(0, 20);  // Set Cursor Position
  display.println("Temperatur"); // Print the this Text
  display.setCursor(22, 40); // Set Cursor Position
  display.println("Control"); // Print the this Text
  display.display(); // Update the Display
  delay(2000); // Delay of 200 ms
}
void set_temp()
{
  if (encoder_btn_count == 2) // check if the button is pressed twice and its in temperature set mode.
  {
    display.clearDisplay(); // clear the display
    display.setTextSize(2); // Set text Size
    display.setCursor(16, 0); // set the diplay cursor
    display.print("Set Temp."); // Print Set Temp. on the display
    display.setCursor(45, 25); // set the cursor
    display.print(set_temperature);// print the set temperature value on the display
    display.display(); // Update the Display
  }
}
void read_encoder() // In this function we read the encoder data and increment the counter if its rotaing clockwise and decrement the counter if its rotating counter clockwis
{
  clockPin = digitalRead(CLK_PIN); // we read the clock pin of the rotary encoder
  if (clockPin != clockPinState  && clockPin == 1) { // if this condition is true then the encoder is rotaing counter clockwise and we decremetn the counter
    if (digitalRead(DATA_PIN) != clockPin) set_temperature = set_temperature - 3;  // decrmetn the counter.
    else  set_temperature = set_temperature + 3; // Encoder is rotating CW so increment
    if (set_temperature < 1 )set_temperature = 1; // if the counter value is less than 1 the set it back to 1
    if (set_temperature > 150 ) set_temperature = 150; //if the counter value is grater than 150 then set it back to 150 
#ifdef __DEBUG__
    Serial.println(set_temperature); // print the set temperature value on the serial monitor window
#endif
  }
  clockPinState = clockPin; // Remember last CLK_PIN state
  
  if ( digitalRead(SW_PIN) == LOW)   //If we detect LOW signal, button is pressed
  {
    if ( millis() - debounce > 80) { //debounce delay
      encoder_btn_count++; // Increment the values 
      if (encoder_btn_count > 2) encoder_btn_count = 1;
#ifdef __DEBUG__
      Serial.println(encoder_btn_count);
#endif
    }
    debounce = millis(); // update the time variable
  }
}
void loop()
{
  read_encoder(); //Call The Read Encoder Function
  set_temp(); // Call the Set Temperature Function
  if (encoder_btn_count == 1) // check if the button is pressed and its in Free Running Mode -- in this mode the arduino continiously updates the screen and adjusts the PWM output according to the temperature.
  {
    temperature_value_c = thermocouple.readCelsius(); // Read the Temperature using the readCelsius methode from MAX6675 Library.
    int output = pid.compute(temperature_value_c);    // Let the PID compute the value, returns the optimal output
    analogWrite(mosfet_pin, output);           // Write the output to the output pin
    pid.setpoint(set_temperature); // Use the setpoint methode of the PID library to
    display.clearDisplay(); // Clear the display
    display.setTextSize(2); // Set text Size
    display.setCursor(16, 0); // Set the Display Cursor
    display.print("Cur Temp."); //Print to the Display
    display.setCursor(45, 25);// Set the Display Cursor
    display.print(temperature_value_c); // Print the Temperature value to the display in celcius
    display.display(); // Update the Display
#ifdef __DEBUG__
    Serial.print(temperature_value_c); // Print the Temperature value in *C on serial monitor
    Serial.print("   "); // Print an Empty Space
    Serial.println(output); // Print the Calculate Output value in the serial monitor.
#endif
    delay(200); // Wait 200ms to update the OLED dispaly.
  }
}
```

Comment: create a minimal sketch to test the encoder

Comment: the encoder works fine, i've tested it seperately

Answer (score 0):

If you can increment the set temperature it means that the statement

> (clockPin != clockPinState  && clockPin == 1)

is true and:

> (digitalRead(DATA_PIN) != clockPin)

is false. So if you rotate the enconder anticlockwise you should guarantee that

> (clockPin != clockPinState  && clockPin == 1)

is still true and

> (digitalRead(DATA_PIN) != clockPin)

is true.
Perhaps this is a little bit obvious but you can start debugging there. Sorry if my english is not clear.